# PGP signature isn't selected when trying to sign during export of PDF-file in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, gnupg, signature, openpgp

I have asked the following question on [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/183723/signature-isnt-selected-when-trying-to-sign-during-export-of-pdf-file-in-writer/) but nobody answered:

> I have an Enigmail PGP signature that I use in Thunderbird under Ubuntu Linux. In Libre Office I can use it to sign (and encrypt) an ODT-document. But when I try to use it during export of a document as a PDF document something goes wrong. In the 'PDF Options' window on the 'Digital Signature' tab, I click on the 'Select' button and get the 'Select Certificate' window. My signature is already selected (it's the only one present). I now click on 'Sign'. The window closes, but the signature isn't shown in the field called "Use this certificate to digitally sign PDF documents:". So when I press the 'Export' button, I get a "signature generation failed" error message, and export of the PDF file fails.
>
> Can anyone help me please?

I also tried signing an existing PDF-file, following the instructions [here](https://vmiklos.hu/blog/pdf-sign.html). In other words:

1. Open LibreOffice Draw
2. File-menu -> Digital Signatures -> Sign existing PDF.
3. Select/open document.
4. Press 'Sign Document' button.

But here, my signature isn't shown, so I can't select it and sign with it.

Comment: I have the same on Debian stretch, with Libreoffice 6.1.5.1 from backports. Which Libreoffice version are you using?

Comment: Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 4.15; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3; 
Locale: da-DK (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group

Comment: I also tried with 6.something on Mint and with the latest 6.3.0.0.alpha+ AppImage. Same results. Maybe submit a bug report?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes - I SHOULD submit a bug report. But bug reporting is often extremely complicated, so I don't know if I will get it done... :-(

Comment: Sadly, it seems LibreOffice right now [only support X.509 certificates](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113278). This [will be explicit](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org//show_bug.cgi?id=115884) on newer versions.